# How to Populate a silverlight chart WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, collections, charts

I need to create a (WP7) chart containing multiple series. The data I'm trying to visualize:

F.ex following collection, containing UserName, Date, Points:

1. User1,2011-11-09,6
2. User2,2011-11-09,8
3. User1,2011-11-02,9
4. User2,2011-11-02,8

There can be more than two users in the data.

#### XAML Namespace

```
xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
```

#### CodeBehind

```
mdChart.Series.Add(MDSeries);                
mdChart.Title = "Statistics";
MDSeries.SetBinding(ColumnSeries.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding());
MDSeries.ItemsSource = lCompetitionStats;
MDSeries.DependentValuePath = "Points";
series.IndependentValuePath = "Date";
MDSeries.IndependentValuePath = "UserName";
```

#### XAML

```
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="mdscores">
    <Grid>
        <charting:Chart x:Name="mdChart" Foreground="Blue" Background="Black">
            <charting:ColumnSeries Background="Black"/>
        </charting:Chart>
    </Grid>
</controls:PanoramaItem>
```

As a result, i have the users on X-axis and Points on the Y-axis. I would need dates on X-axis, Points on Y-Axis and a separate serie for earch user. How to create/populate such a chart runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

#### CodeBehind

```
public class ColumnChartValues
{
    #region Variables
    public string Label { get; private set; }
    public double Value { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor and Initialization
    public ColumnChartValues()
    {
        Label = string.Empty;
        Value = 0;
    }

    public ColumnChartValues(string label, double value)
    {
        Label = label;
        Value = value;
    }
    #endregion
}


public partial class StatsPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<ColumnChartValues> ColumnChartDatabase { get; private set; }

    public StatsPage()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeColumnChart();
    }

    private void InitializeColumnChart()
    {                
        mdChart.Title = "Statistics";

        ColumnChartDatabase = new ObservableCollection<BarChartValues>();
        ColumnChartDatabase.Add(new ColumnChartValues("Value One: ", 1));
        ColumnChartDatabase.Add(new ColumnChartValues("Value Two: ", 2));
        ColumnChartDatabase.Add(new ColumnChartValues("Value Three: ", 3));
    }
}
```

#### XAML

```
<charting:Chart x:Name="mdChart" Foreground="Blue" Background="Black">
    <charting:ColumnSeries  Background="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding ColumnChartDatabase}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Label}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
</charting:Chart>
```

#### FYI

You will have to edit the ColumnChartValues chart to suit your needs